# Access a collection via LINQ and set a single member to a new object

Tags: linq

I am trying to access a user object in a collection with the id = to users101 and set this to another users.

```
Controller.MyObject.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == "user101") = OtherUser();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to update the other user deatils with the details of user101 ? If not plese explain what you mean by " set this to another users".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with one LINQ expression.

Usually LINQ extensions works on enumerables, if `MyObject` is a collection you first have to find the required item and then overwrite it with the new object (moreover `SingleOrDefault()` will simply return null if condition is not satisfied).

You should write something like this (exact code depends on what `MyObject` is):

```
var item = Controller.MyObject.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == "user101");
if (item != null)
    Controller.MyObject[Controller.MyObject.IndexOf(item)] = new OtherUser();
```

Please note that if you do not really need the check performed by `SingleOrDefault()` you can simplify the code (and avoid the double search performed in `SingleOrDefault()` and `IndexOf()`).

If this is "performance critical" maybe it is better to write an ad-hoc implementation that does this task in one single pass.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I was thought I might have to do something like that, its a bit unfortunate but at least it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Try it in two lines:

```
var objectWithId = Controller.MyObject.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == "user101");
(objectWithId as WhateverTypeOfObjectOtherUserIs) = OtherUser();
```